# Wrap the text in a div when the width exceeded

Tags: html, word-wrap

I have a table in which I have 3 columns. The first Column have Name and the Report(s) (i.e. as in the fiddle ACT TSK REM etc.) link below it. The second and third column have some text to display.

I had setup width for div with class "EmployeeReportsLinks" and trying to wrap the text but it's not working the "W" from "NAW" is going in the second line.

Please suggest me for the golbal solution for this.

Here is my html

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="tdfirst" valign="top" style="min-width: 250px; width: auto; text-align: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 5px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(248, 248, 248); height: 68px;">Hello TD1
        <div class="EmployeeReportsLinks" style="width: 200px;display: block; word-wrap: break-word;">ACT&nbsp;TSK&nbsp;REM&nbsp;SAL&nbsp;AFE&nbsp;NAW&nbsp;AW&nbsp;IG&nbsp;CPP&nbsp;COG&nbsp;LS&nbsp;PRE&nbsp;
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tdsecond" valign="top" style="min-width:485px;text-align:left;padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #F8F8F8;">Hello TD2</td>
    <td align="right" valign="top" style="min-width:270px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #F8F8F8;">Hello TD3</td>
</tr>
```

You can find the working example here [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eRT9/)

Comment: Horrible markup, inline styles, nested unnecessary elements, inshort it's a mess...Clean up...

Comment: @Alien I had updated the markup, please have a look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your words are wrapping because you have the style: `word-wrap: break-word;` on your `.EmployeeReportsLinks`

You can either remove that style and all the non-breaking spaces you have entered (`&nbsp;`) or add something like

```
.EmployeeReportsLinks > * {white-space:nowrap;}
```

but this kind of negates the need for the `word-wrap: break-word;`

http://jsfiddle.net/2eRT9/5/ (second option)

Comment: Hello Pete,If you look closer to the fillde there is an empty space in second row. I know that is because of the "&nbsp;" but we need that to separate the a tags. What I need this I want to remove that space from second row; so it'll align with first row. Please help me ASAP.

Comment: why do you need to use a "non breaking spacer" to seperate `a` tags?

Comment: Just for spaces in-between them. You can update the fiddle for spacing between them i.e. by removing the "non breaking spacer"and add some padding or margin between the anchor tags :)

Comment: Can you please reply me ASAP as it's really important and urgent. I tried but it's not working for me?